# Perl exit code 17920 on sendmail

Tags: perl, centos, cgi, sendmail, plesk

i have the problem with my software on my server with plesk.
I send one email from perl script but system return  the following error:

```
error closing /usr/lib/sendmail:  (exit 17920)
```

why recive this error?
In the maillog i recive this error:

```
Jun 29 11:23:57 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx journal: plesk sendmail[7708]: handlers_stderr: PASS
Jun 29 11:23:57 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx journal: plesk sendmail[7708]: PASS during call 'limit-out' handler
Jun 29 11:23:57 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx journal: plesk sendmail[7708]: Unable to rename '/usr/local/psa/handlers/spool/messageEFbeQO' file: Permission denied
Jun 29 11:23:57 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx journal: plesk sendmail[7708]: System error (/usr/local/psa/handlers/spool/messageEFbeQO): No such file or directory
Jun 29 11:23:57 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx journal: plesk sendmail[7710]: Unable to open temporary file `/usr/local/psa/handlers/spool/messageEFbeQO' (2): No such file or directory
```

and i not have idea where the problem.
i hope have said all information.

Comment: `'/usr/local/psa/handlers/spool/messageEFbeQO' file: Permission denied`. Check this error.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by selinux (if it's enabled on your server). You can check that by issuing the command bellow:

```
sestatus
```

If the output says permissive or disabled then selinux is not the issue.

Also this link might help you in fixing your mail problem on your plesk server:
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213947085-Mail-server-does-not-work-How-to-repair-the-mail-server-configuration